# Techniques for mitigating pavement ants during gut reno in bathroom on slab foundation?

Tags: framing, remodeling, slab, contractors, ants

planning a bathroom renovation in a 1950s ranch on slab. Ants appear in several areas where walls meet the floors.

Is there a specific practice for sealing the passageways, that expands/contracts with the seasons, that I can mention to a contractor?

Does the circumstance suggest replacing sill plates, too? Perhaps the ants get in through gaps that form over time around the fasteners into the concrete?

BTW not interested in chemical treatments. Looking for long lasting physical barrier.

Comment: What are pavement ants?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pavement_ant - however I'm making an assumption about the species. Small dark ants common in northern OH.

Comment: Maybe "house" ants.

Comment: You can caulk, and you can expect the ants to chew through the caulking, but since you don't want to use chemicals, you'll have ants. You can use masonry, and it will crack, and you'll have ants in the cracks You can caulk the cracks, and it will slow the ants down until they chew through it....

Comment: I have heard the name sugar ant for the little tiny ones. Boric acid crystals or ground up citrus peals is a non toxic way to deter them.  I have heard diatomaceous earth also works it’s a powder used to coat swimming pool filters (not good to breathe the dust) but is sharp and ants don’t like it. As far as sealing these little buggers will find a way even the drains in windows , my aunt hated ants and I remember her sealing and using Chlordane dust (chemical no longer legal in the states) all the way around her house and at least once a year they would find there way in.

Comment: use boric acid, it's extremely effective and harmless to mammals; they add it to toothpaste. It also prevents mildew/mold and provides fire retardation. there's no real downside to using it that i'm aware of.